# Google map android api v2 application crashes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api, google-maps

I am using Eclipse helios and Android 4.1.2 
i have followed the following documentation https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw and done the coding exactly as described in tutorial.when i run my app on emulator it shows "This app wont run unless you update google play services" but on real device which is sony xperia which  has google play services updated version it crahses with "App has stopped working".Any help is appreciated.

This is my manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.emeterfinalapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
     <permission
         android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enter_location"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.SelectLocation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select_location"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterMainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterMainActivity" />


         </activity>
        </application>
 <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="my api key"/>
    </manifest>
```

here is my main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SelectLocation" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/satellite_button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mapview_button"
        android:text="@string/satellitebuttontext" />


        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         android:layout_below="@+id/satellite_button"/>


        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapview_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/mapbuttontext" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my activity

```
    package com.example.emeterfinalapp;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

        import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

        public class SelectLocation extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_location);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                                           GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)          getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    }


}
```

I gave reference of google_play_services lib to my project added google_play_service and android.support.v4 jar files in my lib....Please if i m still missing anythng please guide....

I have api key which i have added in maifest see above its edited now...

amd here is the error trace from my phone log

```
  I/ActivityManager(  282): Displayed com.example.emeterfinalapp/.EmeterMainActivity:                +206ms
     I/ActivityManager(  282): Displayed com.example.emeterfinalapp/.EnterLocationActivity:      +224ms
     W/InputDispatcher(  282): channel '2c3dbfd0      com.example.emeterfinalapp/com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity (server)' ~           Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
     E/InputDispatcher(  282): channel '2c3dbfd0      com.example.emeterfinalapp/com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity (server)' ~      Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
     W/InputDispatcher(  282): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel      '2c3dbfd0 com.example.emeterfinalapp/com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity      (server)'
     W/InputDispatcher(  282): channel '2c504fb8      com.example.emeterfinalapp/com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterLocationActivity (server)' ~      Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
     E/InputDispatcher(  282): channel '2c504fb8      com.example.emeterfinalapp/com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterLocationActivity (server)' ~      Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
     W/InputDispatcher(  282): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel      '2c504fb8 com.example.emeterfinalapp/com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterLocationActivity      (server)'
```

Comment: Do you have an API key? I don't see this part in your manifest.

Comment: i have an api key i have edited the post...no result til now..m i missing anythng...

Comment: I have also done the same, this code is not working. What exact exception your getting?

Comment: Please post the logcat from your phone...

Comment: can u help me how do i get logcat from my phone...

Comment: As a side note, this error happen in emulator lollipop but not in real device in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whoo...after scratching ma head for so long atlast i got the solution
first i did debugging with real device using DDMS following its documentation which is fabulous then i discovered the following error

```
12-12 15:08:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(26382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.emeterfinalapp/com.example.emeterfinalapp.SelectLocation}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
```

and then after few more lines of code there was another error which was eye catching

```
12-12 15:08:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(26382): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

and then i realised that my api key code is a child of manifest not application which the above error pointed out and then i rectified my manifest to following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.emeterfinalapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
 <permission
     android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterLocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_enter_location"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EmeterMainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.emeterfinalapp.SelectLocation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_select_location"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterMainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.emeterfinalapp.EnterMainActivity" />
    </activity>

     <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="my api key"/>
</application>
```

and then it went like a zoom and everythng worked just perfectly...Debugging with real device helped a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Android Log Viewer (logcat) Application](http://code.google.com/p/alogcat/) for gathering application logs from the phone and seems to work quite well.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the question?

Comment: In order to diagnose possible causes of a crash during the execution of an application is a good practice start looking at the logs. Nevertheless they aren't very accessible while developing applications for Android. Using an application such as the one I mentioned it's handy.