# This app won't run unless you update the google play services - for google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying the example as given in Google maps tutorial. But unable to execute it shows to update the Google play services. when i click on update application crashes. I am fed of trying. please help to solve this problem or please give me any tutorials on Google Maps for android programming.

layout_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mapviewsample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.mapviewsample.MapSampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCQLmBXPhSNhbHBaWH_SDBf1gFu3JNN0H4" />
</application>
```

Comment: I'd try to restart the phone and retry the update one last time, I for one do not know of a workaround for running it properly without updating. http://android.stackexchange.com/ may be a helpful place if you can't get it to update.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start this is llink m using for excuting the google Maps

Answer (score 0):

If you use "android:minSdkVersion="8"",

1.in your layout_man.xml, you must modify  tag as follows;

```
  (X) class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 
  (o) class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

2.For more perfect information, see this link below, which is useful to you;

[click here and then you will see a good tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/)

3
. And please see my recent explanation;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355702/1983061

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 thing to do:

- fix your layout

> class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

to

> class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

- Install google play to your Emulator. You can find in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734937/1821326) and this is [my current config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271933/1821326).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. If you are using the current version of android studio by IntelliJ, in the build.gradle file replace this line

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

with :

```
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
```

and you should be good to go.

This question might be old but hope it helps someone who might be struggling with this.